# Running Java .class files

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile and run my first java program. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. I was able to create and run an Ant Build.xml file. What I can't seem to do is get the .class file to run from the command prompt. First the output I'm getting from the prompt...

```
C:\java>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS
 Volume Serial Number is FA36-A275

 Directory of C:\java

11/27/2014  01:00 PM    <DIR>          .
11/27/2014  01:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/27/2014  01:16 PM             9,029 Main.class
               1 File(s)          9,029 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  831,900,868,608 bytes free

C:\java>java Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

I've also read some things that say "Java looks for a class name, not a file name." In this case they are the same. The first few lines of the Main.java file that I used to build this class file...

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test("C:/data.csv");
//        Solve(8);
    }
```

My code runs properly inside IDEA. Anybody able to explain to me why this isn't working and what I can do to get it going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change directory to the one containing the com folder, then run `java com.company.Main`.

Answer (score 2):

Your Main class is inside `com.company` package. you should give it's full name to the command prompt:

```
java com.company.Main
```

besides, you should add the `.class` file to the classpath:

```
java -cp Main.class com.company.Main
```

Comment: C:\java>java -cp Main.class com.company.Main

Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main

Answer (score 0):

Run it with this command

```
java -cp . Main
```

Comment: C:\java>java -cp . Main

Error: Could not find or load main class Main